# Speed and distance not same on every device

Tags: android, sprite, android-canvas

I have created an Android game using a canvas, but when testing, I have found that the speed and distance of the movements such as flying up or falling down are set right on a phone with a resolution of 1920x1080 (401 ppi). But when I tested on a smaller phone with a resolution of 480 x 854 (196 ppi), I found that the movement of my sprites are a lot quicker which is affecting the gameplay. E.g. The main character sprite jumps a lot higher than I want it to.

Is there any way of keeping the speed and distance the same across all device sizes and types?

Here is some code on how I have implemented the movement:

A sprite class.

```
//class variables
private int GRAVITY_LIMIT = -30;
public int gravity = 0;

//gravity
if(gravity>GRAVITY_LIMIT){
   gravity= gravity-2;
}
//fall
y= y-gravity;
```

Drawing the sprite

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, x, y, null);
```

When onTouch is triggered (Jumping)

```
bird.gravity=30;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another solution.
This one works well.

```
 y= y-(gravity * game.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should base your movement around world coordinates. For example, set your world to be 10meters x 10meters, so that when you jump, you jump 1m. You then need to map that world to screen pixels.

```
float worldHeight = 10f;
float worldToPixels = screenHeight/worldHeight;

y = bird.y * worldToPixels;
```

So, on a 500px height screen, you would jump 50px and on a 1000px height screen you would jump 100px.

Gravity and other forces need to be based on the world as well for it to work on all devices.

Lastly, if you're trying to make a game for multiple devices, it would be better to use a library like [libGDX](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx). There are lots of helpful classes like [ViewPorts](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) to make this easier.

Comment: How do you jump 1m, and how does the gravity work? Im confused... Sorry.